# Decrypting a gpg file with gnupg

Tags: python, gnupg, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt some data from gpg files that I've downloaded. Downloading the files to a directory is no problem, but I'm having trouble actually decrypting them. Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
def extractGPGs(gpglist,path,gpgPath="\"C:\\Program Files\\GNU\\GnuPG\\gpg.exe\""):
os.chdir(path)

if not os.path.isdir("GPGFiles"):
    os.mkdir("GPGFiles")
if not os.path.isdir("OtherFiles"):
    os.mkdir("OtherFiles")

if gpglist == None:
    print "No GPG files found"
    return

try:
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gpgbinary=gpgPath)
except:
    raise "Path to gpg.exe is bad"

print "Extracting GPG Files..."

for filename in gpglist:       

    print "Extracting %s..." % filename
    stream = open(filename,"rb")
    decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt_file(stream,output=".\\OtherFiles")
    stream.close()

print "Finished Extracting GPG Files"
```

And here is the error that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Documents and Settings\nlesniewski\Desktop\downloadData.py", line 281, in <module>
    main(vendor,category)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\nlesniewski\Desktop\downloadData.py", line 273, in main
    extractAndParse.main(info['LocalFolder'])
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\nlesniewski\Desktop\extractAndParse.py", line 147, in main
    extractGPGs(getGPGs(getAllArchives(path)),path)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\nlesniewski\Desktop\extractAndParse.py", line 133, in extractGPGs
    decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt_file(stream,output=".\\OtherFiles")
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\gnupg.py", line 574, in decrypt_file
    os.remove(output) # to avoid overwrite confirmation message
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: '.\\OtherFiles'
```

Why am I getting this error, and, more importantly, how can I decrypt the gpg's?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need the output to be a file name instead of a directory.